# Function evaluation timeout when parcing xml doc

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, parsing, xamarin

I am Parsing xml_doc in my Xamarin project.

When I run the code in the phone emulator in Visual Studio everything is fine.

But when i run the code in my app on phone it throws "Function evaluation timeout"

Code, where throws Error

```
private async Task DisplayForecast(string xml)
        {
            XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();


            xml_doc.LoadXml(xml);

            // Get the city, country, latitude, and longitude.
            XmlNode loc_node = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("weatherdata/location");

           
            var Weathers = new List<WeatherModel>();
     
            foreach (XmlNode time_node in xml_doc.SelectNodes("//time"))
            {
                // Get the time in UTC.
                DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(time_node.Attributes["from"].Value, null, 
                                                       DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
                
                // Get the temperature.
                XmlNode temp_node = time_node.SelectSingleNode("temperature");
                string temp = temp_node.Attributes["value"].Value;

   
                   Weathers.Add(new WeatherModel() //Filling List by data from xml file
                   {
                       Time = time.Hour.ToString() + ":" + time.Minute.ToString(),

                       Temperature = 
                        Convert.ToString(Converter.FahrenheitToCelsius(Convert.ToDouble(temp))) + " ℃",

                       DayOfYear = Convert.ToString(time.DayOfYear),
                     
                       DayOfWeek = time.DayOfWeek.ToString()
                   });      
            }

            var groups = Weathers.GroupBy(p => p.DayOfWeek).Select(g => new Grouping<string, //Grouping List
               WeatherModel>(g.Key,g));
         
            DailyWeatherGroups = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, WeatherModel>>(groups);
            
            OnPropertyChange();
            
        }[![Errors][1]][1]
```

Comment: Did you check to xml input string to see if it contained xml data?  The timeout normally comes from the connection to the server and not in the parsing of the xml.

Comment: Yes, xaml string is filled. When I run the code in the phone emulator everything is fine.

Comment: Where are you getting the timeout?  Do you mean XAML or XML?